# How can i go about creating this complex SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have a table that looks like this:

`Table1`:

```
Time_stamp bigint, << Notice this is bigint and not timestamp, so this needs to be casted
amount int, 
name_ev text, 
badge_number int,
type text
```

(We only want to pull information for rows where the `type` is in `('customer', 'client')`)

And another table that looks like this:

`Table2`:

```
timestamp TIMESTAMP,
low int,
high int
```

(This is by the minute, so every minute has a value low, high)

and a third table that looks like this:

`Table3`:

```
name text,
badge_number text, << Notice this is text and not int, so this needs to be casted
trip_data
```

(There can only exist one name, and one badge_number, meaning no dupes here)

I'm attempting to pull this:

```
timestamp, name, badge_number, highest_Day, lowest_Day, highest_Week, lowest_Week, highest_Month, lowest_Month, trip_data, amount_day, amount_week, amount_month, badge_day, badge_week, badge_month, last_trip_amount, last_trip_time_stamp
```

Explentation:

Explentation:

1. `timestamp`:  The time_stamp from `Table1`
2. `name`: the `name` from `Table1`
3. `badge_number`: the `badge_number` from `Table1`
4. `highest_Day`: a the highest value of `high` in `Table2` Where `Table2.timestamp` is between `Table1.time_stamp - 1 Day` and `Table1.time_stamp`
5. `lowest_Day`: a the highest value of `low` in `Table2` Where `Table2.timestamp` is between `Table1.time_stamp - 1 Day` and `Table1.time_stamp`
6. (The same for Week/Month but instead of Day, it's 1 Week (7 days), and 1 Month (30 Days))...
7. `trip_data`: the value of `trip_data` from `Table3` where `Table3.name` matches `Table1.name_ev` and `Table3.badge_number` matches `Table1_badge_number`
8. `amount_day`: the sum of `amount` from `Table1` for all objects where `Table1.time_stamp` is between `Table1.time_stamp - 1 Day` and `Table1.time_stamp`
9. (The same for Week/Month but instead of Day, it's 1 Week (7 days), and 1 Month (30 Days))...
10. `badge_day`: is the same as amount_day, but only where `Table1.badge_number` matches `Table1.badge_number` and `Table1.time_stamp` is between `Table1.time_stamp - 1 Day` and `Table1.time_stamp`
11. (The same for Week/Month but instead of Day, it's 1 Week (7 days), and 1 Month (30 Days))...
12. `last_trip_amount`: is the value of `Table1.amount` where `Table1.name_ev` and `Table1.badge_number` match the records `name_ev` and `badge_number`
13. `last_trip_time_stamp`: is the same as above, but instead of amount it's the timestamp.

Note that `Table1` is not sorted, and should be sorted on timestamp when retrieving the last object (ie sort by time_stamp desc limit 1) or whatever.

The goal is to pass a `badge_number` and return all records (ie ~15k) in the above response.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.

Comment: Use WITH clauses to split the Big query into several smaller ones, which you can name. Each sub-query will be executed only once, and performance shouldn't be a problem. If your question is more about "how to write SQL queries", you can find documentation online, and even YouTube tutorials if you're in a hurry, just be sure to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: @AR7CORE Perfect! Just peeped some documentation, Exactly what i was looking for, can you submit as an answer so i can mark as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WITH clauses to split the Big query into several smaller ones, which you can name. Each sub-query will be executed only once, and performance shouldn't be a problem.